# store edited values in edittext fields after changed paramaters

Tags: android, json, android-edittext, android-volley

```
public class ActivityEditParent extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG="ActivityEditParent";
    CustomEditText etFirstName,etLastName,etEmail,etPhone;
    public static ConnectionDetector detector;
    private static final String URL = "http://hooshi.me.bh-in-13.webhostbox.net/index.php/parents/editprofile";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private CustomButton btnSave;
    private String parentFirstName,parentLastName,parentPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_parent);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        detector = new ConnectionDetector(ActivityEditParent.this);
        getUIComponents();
    }

    private void getUIComponents(){

        etFirstName = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_first_name);
        etLastName = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_last_name);
        etEmail = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_email_address);
        etPhone = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_phone_number);
        btnSave = (CustomButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_save_parent);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editParent();

            }
        });


        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back);
        title.setText("Edit parent");
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goBack();
            }
        });

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.OOSH_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        String fName = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.PARENT_FNAME,AppConstants.fName);
        String lName = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.PARENT_LNAME,AppConstants.lName);
        String email = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.PARENT_EMAIL,AppConstants.email);
        String phone = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.PARENT_MOBILE,AppConstants.mobile);

        etFirstName.setText(fName);
        etLastName.setText(lName);
        etPhone.setText(phone);
        etEmail.setText(email);

    }


    private void goBack() {
       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityEditDetails.class));
       finish();
    }

    private void editParent(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.OOSH_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        JSONObject jsonParam = null;

        parentFirstName = etFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
        parentLastName = etLastName.getText().toString().trim();
        parentPhone = etPhone.getText().toString().trim();


        if (detector.checkInternet()){
            jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject header = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonParam.put("parentId",preferences.getString(AppConstants.PARENT_ID,""));
                jsonParam.put("parentFN",parentFirstName);
                jsonParam.put("parentLN",parentLastName);
                jsonParam.put("parentPhone",parentPhone);
                jsonParam.put("apiAccessKey",preferences.getString(AppConstants.API_ACCESS_KEY,""));
                header.put("parent",jsonParam);
                Log.d("POST PARAMETERS:",""+header);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, header, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   Log.d("Response:",""+response);

                   String json_status = null;
                   try {
                       json_status = response.getString("status");
                       if (json_status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changed parent details successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityHome.class));
                       }

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }


               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               }
           });

           VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

In the response After getting success message I want save the edited details in in respective edit text fields please help.**After success message I am moving to home screen through intent and again I get back to this screen it is showing the previous details only.**

Answer (score 0):

you want to save data after download from network or after an edit in edit text fields was made??

1. if from network add some  save method execution statement in code where you download data was successful

   ```
    if (json_status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changed parent details successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                  // here you have successful received data so u can map them to edit text or save in shared prefs  
                  // add method to save data here 
                  saveData(response);

                  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityHome.class));
              }


   private void saveData(JSONObject response) {

       // use JSon response object save here to shared preferences 
       // see how to load data from json object 
       // https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject_getString_.html

       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.OOSH_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       sharedPreferences.putString(....).apply;


      // or set edit text controls with JSon data 
   }
   ```
2. to save edit text changes you have two choices :

   - add to layout save button (you have one) button and set on click listener with method to save data:

     ```
     btnSave = (CustomButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_save_parent);
     btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             saveData(v);
         }
     });


     private void saveData(View view) {
         // get root view 
         View rootView = view.getRootView();
         // find edit text widget on root view 
         EditText etFirstName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_first_name);
         // get string from edit text widget 
         String firstName =  etFirstName.getString.toString();

        // get shared preferences 
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.OOSH_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // save to shared prefs firstName wher NAME_KEY is string to identified your saved data for later use - to load 
        sharedPreferences.putString(NAME_KEY,firstName).apply;

     }


     private void loadDataFromSharedPredferences(View view) {
         // get shared preferences 
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.OOSH_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         // load data from shared prefs firstName wher NAME_KEY is string to identified data to load 
         String  firstName = sharedPreferences.getString(NAME_KEY,firstName);
         // get root view 
         View rootView = view.getRootView();
         // find edit text widget on root view 
         EditText etFirstName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_first_name);
         // set string to edit text widget 
         etFirstName.setText(firstName);         
     }
     ```
   - add on text change listener for edittext widgets

**ps. you need to clarify**  - write a exactly steps of what you want to do achieve

- load data from network ? then save ?
- or save request date ?
- or save result data ?

Comment: I want to save the data after changed the text in edit text field, can you show for one edit text field please

Answer (score 0):

all happens here :

```
...
if (json_status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changed parent details successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityHome.class));
}
...
```

once you have a success response save the edited values on the preferences, for example `etFirstName`, save it is new value to the corresponding preference :

```
...
if (json_status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changed parent details successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    editor.putString(AppConstants.PARENT_FNAME, parentFirstName);
    editor.apply(); //don't forget this
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityHome.class));
}
...
```

any way you're creating the editor but not using it.